# Consumir un servicio RestFull en formato JSON con autenticacion en una Java Aplication

Tags: java, json, webservice, rest, auth

Tengo un problema ya que quiero consumir una API Rest el cual debo enviar y recibir un JSON pero ademas para consumir esta api tengo que autenticarme y tiene que ser desde una Java Aplication.
La verdad soy muy nuevo en esto de las API's Rest ya que yo solo me he enfocado en aplicaciones de escritorio y no se como hacerlo espero alguien me pueda ayudar con un ejemplo por que tiene que interactuar una aplicacion java de escritorio con el servicio Rest Autenticado.
Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Que tal amigo @JavierG.Raya te comento como esta mi tema tengo que consumir un servicio Rest el cual envia un JSON y recibe un JSON usando el metodo POST y este debe ser autenticasodo, a continuacion te detallo los requerimientos:
**La autenticación se debe enviar en el header de la petición de la siguiente forma:**
Authorization: Basic user:pass
     Valido aclarar que el valor “user:pass” se debe enviar encriptado base64. Ejemplo:
     Authorization: Basic Z2V0YXVydV9hdXRoX3VzZXI6YXBpd2ViY29tZXJjaW9wYXNzd29yZA==

Comment: Yo ya he probado el consumo desde jsonplaceholder te muestro el codigo:
`//Para convertir una cadena en un objeto
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public <T> T convertirObjeto(final String json, final TypeReference<T> reference){
        try {
            return this.mapper.readValue(json, reference);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrmRestApi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }`

Comment: ` initComponents();
        final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(URI.create("")).build();
        try {
            final HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            List<Post> posts = convertirObjeto(response.body(), new TypeReference<List<Post>>(){});
            posts.stream().forEach(item -> {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{item.getId(),item.getUserId(),item.getTitle(),item.getBody()});
            });
            this.JTRestApi.setModel(model);           
        `

Comment: EN el siguiente enlace dejo el codigo:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/w7jxvbk5ftd37gr/APIREST.rar/file